# Undefined reference to static member variable fixed by adding 0

Tags: c++, class, static, g++

I'm looking to understand the following error that g++ was producing when attempting to link my code. The linking error in question is the following

```
ClassA.cpp:17: undefined reference to `ClassA::xOffset'
ClassA.cpp:17: undefined reference to `ClassA::yOffset'
```

This error comes from this line

```
ClassA::ClassA(int width, int height) : m_width(width - 2 * xOffset), 
                                        m_height(height - 2 * yOffset),
                   ---> error here      m_classB(50, 300,std::make_tuple(xOffset + m_width, xOffset), std::make_tuple(yOffset + m_height, yOffset))
```

The error specifically has to do with creating the tuples and reference the xOffset and yOffset in the second entry in each make_tuple call.

Looking at other questions on SO I noticed people ran into the same issue when not assigning their static member variables. However here's my class definition.

```
class ClassA {
    public:
        ClassA(int width, int height);
        .....

    private:
        static const int xOffset = 150;
        static const int yOffset = 300;

        int m_width;
        int m_height;

        ClassB m_classB;
        ....
};
```

Where both xOffset and yOffset are initialized.

Oddly enough after playing around with the error I can make the linking error go away by changing the initialization line to this

```
ClassA::ClassA(int width, int height) : m_width(width - 2 * xOffset), 
                                        m_height(height - 2 * yOffset),
                                        m_classB(50, 300,std::make_tuple(xOffset + m_width, xOffset + 0), std::make_tuple(yOffset + m_height, yOffset + 0))
```

Where the only change is adding 0 to xOffset and yOffset. This removes the linking error and allows me to compile and run my code.

My question is why does adding + 0 fix a linking error, and why could I reference the static variables xOffset and yOffset in the initialization list when creating m_width and m_height but doing so again in the next item in the initialization list cause an linker error?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your cpp-file need to add:

```
const int ClassA::xOffset;
const int ClassA::yOffset;
```

Comment: I was able to fix it, but I was hoping to understand why this error was occurring :)